# deleting user input column range using an array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to learn using arrays.

Below code is a user will input a range then check the range for a value "abc" in each row 1 then add it to an array then with the array values of column numbers delete the entire column, below code has an error saying type mismatch saying x is empty.

```
  Option Explicit

   Sub delete_column()

   Dim arr As Variant, x As Integer, myrange As String, rng As Range, cell, 
   item as Variant

     Set arr = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
       myrange = InputBox("Please enter the range:", "Range")
       If myrange = "" Then Exit Sub
     Set rng = Range(myrange)

   For Each cell In rng
       If cell.Value = "abc" Then arr.Add cell.Column
   Next cell

   For x = UBound(arr) To LBound(arr)
      Cells(1, arr(x)).EntireColumn.Delete
   Next x

   End Sub
```

I can't figure out how to fix the error. After the error shows of type mismatch when I hover my mouse to the x it says empty. When I hover my mouse to the arr(x) it has the correct column number.

I used `For x = UBound(arr) To LBound(arr) Step -1` still error

I used below but it only deleted some of the columns not all with values of abc.

For Each item In arr
Cells(1, item).EntireColumn.Delete
Next item

Comment: In your For loop you want x to count down from UBound(arr) to LBound(arr).  To count down you need to add `Step -1` to the for loop line

Comment: That said, you might want to use a For Each to iterate the ArrayList

Comment: used the step -1 but still with error also the for each loop it did not delete all the column with values of abc only a few

Comment: Just to step back a bit, why are you using an ArrayList instead of a VBA array?

Comment: its a code i found to add value to an array, im trying to learn more about arrays i think arrays are faster when manipulating data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the methods `Ubound()` and `Lbound()` on a variant.  If you want to use an array, you have to declare `arr` with parenthesis.  Below I've declared arr as an array of integers.

```
Option Explicit

Sub delete_column()

Dim arr() As Integer, x As Integer, myrange As String, rng As Range, item As Variant, cell
        
myrange = InputBox("Please enter the range:", "Range")
If myrange = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Set rng = Range(myrange)
        
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "abc" Then
        If (Not Not arr) = 0 Then'check if arr is not dimensioned
            ReDim arr(0) 'dimension the array
            arr(UBound(arr)) = cell.Column
        Else
            ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)'expand the array by 1
            arr(UBound(arr)) = cell.Column
       End If
    End If
Next cell

For x = UBound(arr) To LBound(arr) Step -1
    Cells(1, arr(x)).EntireColumn.Delete
Next x

   End Sub
```

Comment: would this be the best practice to add data to an array instead of the createobject arraylist?

Comment: IMO, yes.  As it was, your code was dependent on including the 'System' reference.  I mean, your code works fine, but you wanted to learn arrays and this is how you use an array.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution below using .count, i dont know why iteration with ubound and lbound did not work

'''

```
  Option Explicit

   Sub delete_column()

   Dim arr As Variant, x As Integer, myrange As String, rng As Range, cell

   Set arr = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    myrange = InputBox("Please enter the range:", "Range")
       If myrange = "" Then Exit Sub
   Set rng = Range(myrange)

   For Each cell In rng
       If cell.Value = "abc" Then arr.Add cell.Column
   Next cell

   For x = arr.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
          Cells(1, arr(x)).EntireColumn.Delete
   Next

   End Sub
```

'''

Comment: That's because you never decarded arr as an array.  You declared it as a variant which doesn't allow the methods Ubound and Lbound.